# PHP/Symfony2, two classes in one file, which should be first?

Tags: php, symfony

I've got something that's strange for me. It's in Symfony Controller, but I don't think that matters. In the controller file, next to controller class I created a simple "class" with consts just to keep some things in queries more clear:

```
class ExportType
{
    const EXPORT_WORLDWIDE = 1;
    const EXPORT_EU = 2;
}
```

Of course there's only one namespace at the top. These constants are used in one of the controller's actions.

Every time I use PhpStorm's code autoformatting, that class is moved to the top of the file. OK, I don't mind and PhpStorm doesn't report any error here. But seems like PHP (or Symfony?) doesn't like it, because every time that helper class is on the top, there's a `FileLoaderLoadException` thrown, saying that class doesn't exist in this namespace.
When it's at the bottom, there's no problem. Is it normal? Should used class be declared after the class that is using it??

Comment: Silly question: why don't you move those class in other files? I mean, what's the advantage of keep them in same file? Secondo silly question: because you use symfony, why don't you take advantage of `parameters.yml` file or environment files to define such constant? That way you can retrive them through all your application

Comment: Please show a relevant portion of your controller method code which uses your helper class.  You might have a namespace issue.  I do this sort of thing all the time and never noticed a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem probably comes from Composer, you code is simply not PSR-0/4 compliant which is convention Composer is using to autoload your files. You get an error because it can't find the file to load because of that.

It probably works if declared as second because the only place where you are using it is in your Controller. Use your constant somewhere else and it will automatically fail.

Comment: So looks like I should put all such constant-only classes into separate folder and namespace to use them? That just seemed like it doesn't have much sense if they're used only from one file, but I assume that's the PSR-compliant way...

Comment: Basically yeah. If you are using Composer it's a 1 file per class. If you want a file where you declare functions, constants etc., you have to add them to your `composer.json` with the `files` directive: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: @Théo Neither psr4 nor composer cares if you have multiple classes in one file.  You might not be able to autoload them but as long as long as the files itself end up being loaded then all is well.

Comment: >You might not be able to autoload

Which was the problem, precisely because Composer cares.